# AppleScript running Shell Script: permissions issues with mkdir and cp

Tags: macos, bash, shell, applescript

I'm trying to build a basic app that is to be used on multiple machines with variable home folder names that will create a directory and copy the contents of a folder in location A to this new directory. The directory is important as it needs to live in the Library of the User folder.

```
#!/bin/sh

moveFile="$HOME/Desktop/Updater/Test Folder 1/test.txt"
newFolder="$HOME/Desktop/Updater/Test Folder 2"
mkdir "$newFolder"
cp "$moveFile" "$newFolder"
```

While building the guts of it with a shell script, i'm able to run the script in Terminal just fine.  However, when I use the AppleScript to call the script, it will say that permission is denied:

```
do shell script "bash $HOME/Desktop/Updater/updater.sh" with administrator privileges

cp: $HOME/Desktop/Updater/Test Folder 2/test.txt: Permission denied
```

Obviously, to get around this I will add administrator privileges:

```
do shell script "bash $HOME/Desktop/Updater/updater.sh" with administrator privileges
```

The problem with this, is that it will modify the permissions of the folder and file to that of system.  This breaks another part of another app that uses these moved files since user permissions have been removed and replaced with that of system.

My question is this: how do I ensure that AppleScript's execution of the shell script doesn't mangle my permissions copying files from one location to another?

Answer (score 1):

use `-p` option with `cp`.

```
cp -p "$moveFile" "$newFolder"
```

Script

```
#!/bin/sh

moveFile="$HOME/121/anchor”
newFolder="$HOME/121/Updater/“
mkdir "$newFolder"
sudo chmod u+rwX,go+rX "$newFolder"
sudo chown “$1”
cp -p "$moveFile" "$newFolder"
```

Applescript

```
set myUsername to (short user name of (system info))
do shell script "bash $HOME/p.sh " & myUsername with administrator privileges
```